# Invert the split action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I just modified my action bar on my application to use the Split ActionBar functionality described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar

I created a draft custom view in order to see the result on my device, here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right" >
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/action1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/action2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In my Activity, I just modified my code to add the two required lines to set this custom XML and the way it should be displayed:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_bottom); //load bottom menu
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME|ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.show();
```

The split is working well, my problem is that the action bar I was using previously is now at the bottom of the screen and the new one defined in the XML above is now displayed at the top of the screen, along with the Home button.

I looked at the function [setDisplayOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayOptions%28int,%20int%29) in the developer guide but it is not really clear for me how to use it. 
Is there an easy way to invert the 2 action bars in order to let my main action bar at the top?

Thank you!